# Automate setcommands in Telegram

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Is it possible to automate the setcommands command?
Instead of going to Botfather. Is there any way to doing from my code using Telegram API or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Telegram Bot API currently doesn't support interacting with other bots. If you really need adding commands to your bot programmatically, go through [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/#telegram-api) (Don't confuse it with Bot API. This API is used for creating telegram clients, not bots) and contact @BotFather.
However, doing that doesn't seem reasonable. Instead, there might be a simpler approach so you don't need to add commands to your bot programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this wasn't the case when this was asked, but currently (2023), the Telegram Bot API does have a ***setMyCommands* method**.

So, using the bot API, you can send a request to `https://api.telegram.org/bot<API_KEY>/setMyCommands`.

Details here: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setmycommands